# Why when modifing a BATCH Veriable Value in one function it appears, but shows as blank in another function?

Tags: function, validation, batch-file

To my knowlege all variables which aren't explicitly local, should be global;
however I have problems with the returned value when calling `Total Lines`. I can see it modified to `9` during the `Get total Lines` call, however after returning to the `File Arrays` function, this appears to be blank, (going off what I can see in my `Flow log`).

FileToArrays Function

```
:FileToArrays
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: logs info to the log file V
@echo Requesting total line count>>Flow.log

Call :GetTotalLines 
::   ^ grabs total Lines within the Map file.

@echo TotalLines Obtained : %TotalLines%>>Flow.log

set /a CurrentLine = 0
::   ^ Adds a empty Int

@echo Scanning Lines and building Char Array>>Flow.log
@echo Calling String to char>>Flow.log
@echo CurrentLine Obtained : !CurrentLine!>>Flow.log
Call :CharLoop
pause 
goto :eof
```

Get total Lines Function

```
:GetTotalLines
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::  V File to be Scanned
set "File=!RoomToLoad!.Map"

:: V holder for the total line count.
set /a TotalLines=0

:: for each Line within the file do the DO section
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%P in (%File%) do (

    :: increases the total line count of that file.
    set /a TotalLines=!TotalLines!+1
)

:: V logs info into the log file.
@echo Total Lines Reported to be !totalLines!>>Flow.log

goto :eof 
:: ^Exits subroutine to return to the Caller
```

Flow.log output

```
Requesting total line count
Total Lines Reported to be 9
TotalLines Obtained : 
Scanning Lines and building Char Array
Calling String to char
CurrentLine Obtained : 0
IN CHAR LOOP
```

Could some kind soul advise where I seem to have gone wrong here?

Edit - For a little extra Clarity `total lines obtained` and `total lines reported` should match within the log.

Comment: Do not use broken labels ```::``` for comments/remarks! There is built-in a `REM` command for exactly that purpose.

Comment: Appologies i was under the impression they were interchangable, will ammend

Comment: Best practice is to place the redirection before the echo statement for cases where the value being echoed is an integer matching a valid file handle.
EI: `>>"filepath.ext" Echo(!Variable!`

Answer (score 0):

Okay took me a few hours and now i feel a little wiser for it,
Yes all Items are held globaly BUT the `setlocal` part of `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` means that all subsiquent verables basicly get placed in their own box.

I had 3 set local EnabledelayedExpansions, 1 on the main script that called these subroutines and one on each some routine.

Each one of them acted as another sub container

[As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCUQH.png)

The solution in my case was to remove the redundent `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`'s and it worked fine.

Hope this helps anyone else who has this headache one day.

Comment: `setlocal` starts a `local` environment with a copy of the current environment. Executing an `endlocal` restores the original environment. **Reaching end-of-file** (whether by executing the last physical line of the file, or `goto :eof`) is an **implicit endlocal**. To transport a modified variable back to the original environment, use `endlocal&set "varname=%varname%"`. `Cmd` then substitutes the current value of `varname` and executes `endlocal&set "varname=varnamescurrentvalue"` which disposes of the local environment and `set`s the value in the original environment.